# as though,as if

Tags: word-usage, usage

Are AS IF and AS THOUGH  interchangeable?

> 1 You look **as though/as if** you haven't slept for weeks.
>   2 It  felt **as though/as if** it was summer already.
>   3 He looked **as though/as if** he hadn't taken a shower for days.

Also, is it correct to say

> **He** looked **as if/as though** he hadn't taken a shower for days.

or should it be

> **It** looked **as though/as if** he hadn't taken a shower for days.

Comment: This looks like two questions...maybe open another question for He vs. It?

Answer (score 2):

They are virtually synonymous but to my ear, "as if" connotes a counterfactual:

> It felt as if it were summer already, although it was still March.

(Note that you write ["were", not "was"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood)).

"As though" does not have (again to my ear) that hint of "but it's not!"

> You look as if you haven't slept well, but I heard you snoring.

But

> You look as though you haven't slept for weeks.

That is literally counterfactual, because you have in fact slept in the last few days, but the expression was not meant to be taken literally.

Very subtle distinction.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is the same. "as though" is more formal.

Comment: Here is the thing that confuses me. Taken from Cambridge dictionary : (We use If only talk about a wish for the future or to show a contrast between how things are and how we would like them to be, we use if only + would + infinitive without to:If only someone would buy the house.If only they would talk to each other. According to this, when could I specifically use WOULD with if only?

Comment: @juan Your comment seems unrelated to this question. Maybe you meant to post it on this question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/136842/if-onlywould-have-could-have

Comment: Also, why the vote to delete instead of down voting? Can someone explain if this answer violates some policy?

Comment: Answers without explanations do not teach the patterns of the language well. When someone has already demonstrated the ability to provide a cogent explanation, perhaps more is expected of them than a one-liner. But that's just a guess.

Comment: ok...but still why not just downvote?